# Передача компаратора в контейнер

Tags: c++

Задам вопрос на простом примере:

```
using Functor = std::greater_equal<string>;
istringstream stream("used namespace std,  and included header files");
std::istream_iterator<string> IF(stream), IL;
set<string, Functor> ss(IF, IL);
for (string s : ss) {
    auto p = s.rbegin();
    if (!isalnum(*p))
        s.erase(p.base() - 1);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Понятно, что слова выведутся в порядке, определенным указанным типом компаратора в шаблоне `set`...(в данном случаи в обратом порядке лексикографического). Но компаратор также можно передать и в конструктор обьекта.

### Вопросы:

1. Почему обьявление  `set<string> ss(IF, IL, Functor());` неправильно?
2. Так, как это сделать?
3. В каких случаях понадобится передать
       компаратор в конструктор, а не его тип в шаблон?..

Comment: Чтобы контейнер использовал нужный компоратор, нужно передать его вместе с параметрами типа: `set<string, Funcotor> ss();`. Также можно передавать его как аргумент, что полезно, если компоратор представлен функцией или лямбда-выражением. Тогда это будет выглядеть вроде: `set<string, decltype(comp)>ss(comp);`. Если, конечно, я не ошибся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Так ведь если вы не указываете параметр типа - берется параметр по умолчанию (`less<>`). Это шаблон класса, а не функции, тут вывод не сработает.
2. `set<string, Functor> ss(IF, IL, Functor());` Хотя `Functor()` можно и не писать, потому что это значение по умолчанию. Но вот если у вас какой-то хитрый функтор, например, с параметром - `set<string, Functor> ss(IF, IL, Functor("xyz"));` - то его придется писать в обязательном порядке...

Comment: Извените, но  using Functor = std::greater_equal<string>; это не значение по умолчанию

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `std::greater_equal<string>()` - значение по умолчанию, передаваемое в конструктор `set` (обратите внимание, что я написал не *`Functor`  можно не писать*, а *`Functor()`  можно не писать*).

Comment: Ах да, ну все понел, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Компаратор должен передаваться **и** через список параметров шаблона, **и** через параметр конструктора объекта. Через список параметров шаблона передается *тип* компаратора, а через параметр конструктора объекта - *значение* компаратора.

Объявление

```
set<string> ss(IF, IL, Functor());
```

является неправильным потому, что в списке аргументов шаблона использован аргумент по умолчанию - *тип* компаратора `std::less<string>`, а в качестве *значения* компаратора передается значение типа `std::greater_equal<string>`. Несоответствие типов и вызывает ошибку.

Вы, однако, можете воспользоваться дедукцией шаблонных аргументов в С++17 и написать просто

```
set ss(IF, IL, Functor());
```

Передача типа компаратора (и типа элемента) через параметры шаблона в этом случае все равно делается, но ее делает за вас компилятор через стандартные *deduction guides* для `std::set`. "Частичной" дедукции, правда, нет, т.е. дедукция работает только когда шаблонные аргументы отсутствуют полностью, вместе с `<>` скобками.

От указания типа компаратора через параметры шаблона можно было бы избавиться, если бы в качестве компаратора всегда использоваться объект типа `std::function`. Но в дизайне стандартных контейнеров так не делается. Разрабатывались они еще до того, как в стандартной библиотеке появилась `std::function`. Также, за удобство `std::function` надо платить накладными расходами.

Comment: Очень полезная информация.  Подробно  и понятно...

Answer (score 1):

1. вы не указали параметр критерия сортировки, где по умолчанию используется `less`
2. в данном случае достаточно `set<string, Functor> ss();`
3. данный случай используется для компараторов представленных например ввиде лямбда-выражений, тогда

   `auto alfa = [](){/*какое-то тело*/};`

   `set<string, decltype(alfa)>ss(alfa);`

Comment: И какой же параметр я не указал?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan критерий `less` - забыл указать в ответе

Comment: и почему  достаточно set<string, Functor> ss(), если я создаю обьект  с данными из потока?

Comment: Мне не нужен less, я  сравниваю по другому критерию. Я вас не очень понимаю

Comment: @ARHovsepyan да, вам то `less` не нужен, но вот только откуда это знать компилятору? Раз не указано ничего, то он берет его. Тут, все-таки наверно нужно в ответе не `не указали less` а `не указали критерий сортировки`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan что касается `создаю объект из потока` - тут я не совсем понял о чем вы?

Comment: читайте пожалуйста повнимательней: я написал " создаю обьект с данными из потока" ,  а не "создаю обьект  из потока ".  Теперь все понятно, что вы хотели сказать, и это конечно полезный ответ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan просто небольшая опечатка - пропустил слово когда печатал